# Will my bluetooth keyboard/mouse autoconnect on a reboot without any extra work?

Tags: boot, 20.04, keyboard, bluetooth, mouse

I'm very new to Linux so I apologize if this is a very rudimentary question. That being said, I am planning on buying Bluetooth peripherals. (Microsoft Designer Compact Keyboard & Microsoft Bluetooth Ergonomic Mouse) And I need to know before I get them, if they will automatically connect to my computer on boot. I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS aarch64 with the Ubuntu Mate environment. All help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, yes. Hardware is automatically discovered on boot, so no additional steps than having your Bluetooth USB dongle plugged in is required.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the question concerned a Bluetooth dongle, it concerned a bluetooth mouse and keyboard. The following worked for me:

Switch on the devices and put them in pairing mode. Open the bluetooth settings and click on the + sign at the bottom. Select your devices and pair them. Note their bluetooth addresses (6 pairs of hexadecimal digits separated by colons e.g. 0F:1E:2D:3C:4B:5A)

Now open a terminal e.g. with Ctrl+Alt+T

Enter bluetoothctl

Enter trust 0F:1E:2D:3C:4B:5A (i.e. the bluetooth address you noted earlier)

When the system responds that it trusts your device, repeat trust 0F:1E:2D:3C:4B:5A with the next device's address.

When you're finished, enter Exit.

Now your devices should connect automatically next time you boot.